# Does $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to solve

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}$$

Does this converge or diverge and why?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Can you share what you've tried, and what you're having trouble with? Do you know the ratio test, or any related tests for convergence?

Comment: I know very little about the topic, if you could please give me some information about it as well as the answer to this it would be appreciated

Comment: @NotFreddy Read about the [ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), either on Wikipedia or in your textbook.

Comment: Do you know the Stirling approximation for the factorial?  That should make this problem nearly trivial...

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will dig into the stirling aproximation of the factorial as i have never heard of it

Comment: See [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: Duplicate: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835311/does-this-sum-converge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [d'Alembert's ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test)

$\sqrt{\frac{(j+1)!}{(j+1)^{j+1}}}\sqrt{\frac{j^j}{j!}} = \sqrt{\frac{(j+1)!}{j!}\frac{j^j}{(j+1)^{j+1}}} = \sqrt{\frac{j^{j+1}+j^j}{(j+1)^{j+1}}}$

You can now show that this quantity converges to some real number smaller than one in order to conclude.

Comment: Right, the ratio is $\lt1$ for every $j$ (not only for $j$ large enough)... **and so what?** Note that the approach in this answer would also "prove" that $\sum\limits_n\frac1n$ converges since $\frac1{n+1}\frac{n}1\lt1$ for every $n$. @upvoters: Why the upvote?

Comment: Actually you are right the argument is not complete enough and if go until the end then I come on the answer of Strants..

Answer (score 10):

Note for $j>4$
$$
{j!\over j^j}=
\underbrace{ {j\over j}\cdot{j-1\over j}\cdot{j-2\over j}\cdots\cdot{4\over j}}_{<1}\cdot{3\over j}\cdot{2\over j}\cdot{1\over j}<{6\over j^3}.
$$
So for $j>4$, we have $$\sqrt{j!\over j^j}<{\sqrt 6\over j^{3/2}}.$$

If you know that the [$p$-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty{1\over j^{3/2}}$ converges (it does), then you can use the [Comparison Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) to deduce that your series converges.

Answer (score 3):

[Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) states that that 
$$n!\sim n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2n\pi}.$$

Thus,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left( \frac{n!}{n^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$$ 
and the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

We can observe that 
$$\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{(j+1)!}{(j+1)^{j+1}}}}{\sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}} 
= \sqrt{\frac{(j+1)!j^j}{j!(j+1)^{j+1}}} = \sqrt{\frac{j^j}{(j+1)^j}} = \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)^j\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Thus, 
$$L = \lim_{j\to\infty} \left|\frac{a_{j+1}}{a_j}\right| = \left(\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{j}\right)^j\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}} < 1,$$

so the sequence converges by the ratio test.