# Does this Sum converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to solve $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}$

Does this converge or diverge?

Comment: We saw your question the first time, no need to re-post. The problem is you are on the wrong side of town - this is about *Mathematica*, not about Mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Using Stirling's Formula, we have
$$
j!\sim\sqrt{2\pi j}\left(\frac{j}{e}\right)^j
$$
Since $j\le e^j$ for all $j$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}
&\sim\frac{(2\pi j)^{1/4}}{e^{j/2}}\\
&\le\frac{(2\pi)^{1/4}}{e^{j/4}}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}
$$
converges.

---

Using the ratio test, we have
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{(j+1)!}{(j+1)^{j+1}}}}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{j!}{j^j}}}=\frac1{\sqrt{\left(1+\frac1j\right)^j}}\to\frac1{\sqrt{e}}\lt1
$$
thus, the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Sum[Sqrt[j!/j^j], {j, #}] & /@ Range@30

ListLinePlot@x
```

[image]

Now decide for yourself :)

Comment: NSum[Sqrt[j!/j^j], {j, 1, Infinity}] produces $3.01278 $.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a bit further along user64494 's track:
`NSum[Sqrt[j!/j^j], {j, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 96]`
`(* 3.01277702345391  *)`
Maybe even further along:
`Sum[Sqrt[j!/j^j],{j,1,31}];
N[%,24]`
`(*3.01277593270324582978550*)`
and the rest from j=32 to infinity can be approximated by:
`NSum[Normal[Series[Sqrt[j!/j^j],{j,\[Infinity],12}]], {j, 32, \[Infinity]}, WorkingPrecision -> 96, AccuracyGoal -> 48]`
`(*1.09075065225228693*10^-6*)`
to give a total of  `3.01277702345389808207242`
As to your question of convergence, remark that each term is majored by `Sqrt[2^(j-1)]` whose sum converges to `2+Sqrt[2]`